# isInViewport inside scroll funtion triggers my pages content only after scrolling the first bit. Is there any way to avoid this?

Tags: function, scroll, viewport

For this assignment, the particular content needs to be in the scroll function because there's certain interactions for each scene. However, the content doesn't appear before scrolling which makes sense obviously. My question is if there is any way to get around this issue? Because I get all the content on the page except the content that sits in my scroll function.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  $(".scenes").each(function (index) {

    $.fn.isInViewport = function () {
      var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
      var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
      var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

      return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
    };

    index = index + 1
    // console.log(index);
    index = nummer - index * nummer / totaal;

    $(this).css({
      'background': 'hsl(85, 70%,' + index + '%)',

    });

    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      console.log(this);
      if ($(this).attr("id") == "scene1") {
        ViewportCount = 1;
      } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "scene2") {
        ViewportCount = 2;
      } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "scene3") {
        ViewportCount = 3;
      } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "scene4") {
        ViewportCount = 4;
      } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "scene5") {
        ViewportCount = 5;
      } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "scene6") {
        ViewportCount = 6;
      }
      console.log($(this).attr("id") + " is visible");
    } else {
      console.log($(this).attr("id") + " is hidden")
    }
```